# misunderstanding class in customtkinter (Tkinter)

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I'm making page transition program with customtkinter, and understanding example codes on internet.
But I have question when experimenting code.

```
import tkinter
import customtkinter

class App(customtkinter.CTk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        container = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self)
        container.pack(expand = True, fill = 'both')
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        self.frames['MotivationPage'] = MotivationPage(container, self)
        self.frames['BodyInfoPage'] = BodyInfoPage(container, self)

        for F in ('MotivationPage', 'BodyInfoPage'):
            self.frames[F].grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = 'news')
    
        self.show_frame('MotivationPage')
    
    def show_frame(self, page_class):
            frame = self.frames[page_class]
            frame.tkraise()

    

class MotivationPage(customtkinter.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        customtkinter.CTkFrame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1) 
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

        print(type(controller))
        self.controller = controller

        self.btn1 = customtkinter.CTkButton(self, text = 'asdasd', **command = lambda:controller.show_frame('BodyInfoPage'))**
        self.btn1.pack()



class BodyInfoPage(customtkinter.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        customtkinter.CTkFrame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.controller = controller

        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

        self.label1 = customtkinter.CTkLabel(self, text = 'asdasdasdasd')
        self.label1.pack()

a = App()
a.mainloop()
```

I think MotivationPage's `__init__` method inherited container(parent) and class `App`(controller)
But I cannot understand why it doesn't work when I change
`lambda:controller.show_frame('BodyInfoPage')`
to
`lambda:App.show_frame('BodyInfoPage')`

terminal says

```
TypeError: App.show_frame() missing 1 required positional argument: 'page_class'
```

when I change it to
`lambda:App.show_frame(App, 'BodyInfoPage')`
it doesn't work either.

I want to know why it doesn't work when I change like that.

Comment: Note that `App` is the class name, so when you use `App.show_frame(...)`, you need to pass the instance of `App` as the first argument, like `App.show_frame(controller, ...)`.  But if you use `controller.show_frame(...)`, you don't need the instance because `controller` is the instance.